# Can we define batches on basis records rather than time(interval) in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, batch-processing

Is there a way to define batch definition in spark streaming such that, each RDD represent a record rather than data of a time interval.

Comment: No, it is not possible. How would it even work?

Comment: If you want a record, why do not you iterate over the RDD!!! What is your exact requirement.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. @Rakesh, RDD are the micro-batches from stream received during a time interval. Now, I want each micro-batch (RDD) to be a record, rather than records received in a time interval. At the end I want to iterate over a record in spark streaming.